# Handle whitespace in Neo4j full text search

Tags: neo4j

I need some help with full text search.

I have created an index like so:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex("ReasourceName",["Resource"],["name"])
```

I can query it and get results:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('ReasourceName', 'bmc pumping station~') YIELD node, score 
WITH node, score 
RETURN node.name, score
limit 10;
```

output:

```
╒════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════╕
│"node.name"                     │"score"           │
╞════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│"BMC Pumping Station"           │8.143752098083496 │
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"BMC Office"                    │2.944127082824707 │
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"BMC Office"                    │2.944127082824707 │
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"BMC Dispensary"                │2.944127082824707 │
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"BMC Office"                    │2.944127082824707 │
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"BMC Dispensary"                │2.944127082824707 │
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"BMC Office"                    │2.944127082824707 │
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"Police Station"                │2.6569595336914062│
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"Momo Station"                  │2.6569595336914062│
├────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────┤
│"BMC Shikshak Bhavan"           │2.515393018722534 │
└────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

However it performs poorly if the input query differs in whitespace. For example, I would expect the query `bmcpumpingstation` or `bmcpumpingstation~` to have a similar result set, however it returns nothing.

There does not appear to be an analyzer that works on levenshtein distance.

(I also asked this question on [neo4j community](https://community.neo4j.com/t/handle-whitespace-in-full-text-search/47534) but didn't get a response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying engine is `Lucene` and the flow is that it tokenizes the text and store it as tokens.

Then when you "search", it tokenize your search string and compare tokens between your search and what is in the indexes.

I would suggest to read this article ( note Neo4j did some changes but 90% is still valid today ) : https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2019/01/11/neo4j-full-text-search-deep-dive.html

So, if you search for `bmcpumpingstation` and your index contains the following tokens :

`bmc`, `pumping`, `station`

Then there is simply no match.

If you want to hack a bit and have this type of search working, you can create a dedicated index for this and remove all whitespaces from the names when you index it, then you can use `bmcpumpingstation` with some fuzziness to search

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to clean up your data!

```
match (m:Resource) set m.name=replace(m.node,"~","")
```

or do the clean up before loading the data.